# R plot confidence interval with lm and leveragePlots

Tags: r, linear-regression

I m using R lm() function to make a multiple linear regression

```
lmfit <- lm(formula = `Var1` ~
          `Var2`
        + `Var3`
        + `Var4`,
        data=df)
```

Then the leveragePlots function from car library

```
library(car)
leveragePlots(lmfit)
```

This gives me plots with linear regression for each Var but I haven't find a way to display the confidence interval. Can you please help?

[image: The plot I got with leveragePlot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably seem like a very round about way of doing what you want as I don't know how to do it in `leveragePlots()` but here I used ggplot2 which provides a lot of flexibility. You will need all of these packages installed which you can do with `install.packages(c('ggplot2', 'magrittr', 'gridExtra', 'purrr'))`. I use the `mtcars` dataset in this example because it comes built in with R. So you can run this code as is and see what is happening. Just replace the `mtcars` and my variables with yours, and you should get what you want.

```
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(gridExtra)
library(purrr)

# provide the data, x variable, y variable and this function will
# create a scatterplot with a linear model fit
create_plots <- function(df, xvar, yvar) {
  if (!is.character(xvar) | !is.character(yvar)) {
    stop('xvar and yvar must but characters/strings')
  }

  plot <- df %>% 
            ggplot(aes_string(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + 
            geom_point() +
            geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = T)
  plot
}

# map over all the variables for which you would like to create plots
graphs <- purrr::map(c('disp', 'wt'), create_plots, df = mtcars,
                     yvar = 'hp')
first_plot <- graphs[[1]] # save the results in variables
second_plot <- graphs[[2]]

grid.arrange(first_plot, second_plot) # combine the plots
```